# How to get started with map overlays and tiles

Tags: openlayers-2, tilecache, tilemill

I have put quite some time into doing my own research and know in theory what i want to do and some of the steps involved in doing it but I wanted to put this question out to ensure i'm not going in completely the wrong direction and in the hope that some who have trodden this path before might be able to help me avoid some pitfalls.

Target.

I have a need to create a website with an interactive map that will display a base layer of google or OSM (i already have that created)  i then need to overlay a layer that i will create (this is where i need help) and finally server up markers that can be touched (planned to use Mysql and php to build the marker list)

I have a source of Geo TiFFs that i need to stitch together to form a layer and I then need to create tiles from that layer and server it up.  I also have a database of markers

I have several tools GDAL , tilemill, (tried tile map didn't work), QGIS, OpenGEO.

Questions.

1. Does this sound like the right approach to tackling the problem.
2. How do i get over the knowledge gap of processing the tiffs into a layer
3. Should i serve the layer as a sequence of html folders or from a database and if so what does it need to be a GIS.

Comment: OK so I tried taking the Geo Tiffs and adding them as raster layers in QGIS in preparation to tiling.  but they seem to all overlap each other rather than fan out over the overview screen.  E.G.  if i import two the show adjacent to one another (north / south) but if i import the next two geo tiff down they just overlay rather than positioning themselves to the north or south !!!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have access to some kind of geospatial server such as GeoServer, MapServer, or access to any ESRI Server products, rendering the GeoTiffs will be a problem.

What I have done in the past when lacking a geospatial server was convert what I can via QGIS to a geojson file. QGIS can handle several formats of data which can be exported in several formats as well. Look into OpenLayers, a JavaScript library for displaying and editing mapps/data in serveral formats.

To get an idea of what can be done with the data you have check out the OpenLayers examples at http://openlayers.org/ and GeoEXT which employs OpenLayers at http://geoext.org/. These are just a few of many options that are possible.

Hope this will get you started.

Also check out this site which has some decent tutorial on popular GIS software. http://www.gistutor.com/

Comment: What would be the steps to import and create tiles assuming I have an up and running geoserver ??

Comment: I also need to trim the maps to get rid of legends. how would these be handled in the import to a geo server